# How to add a SSL Certificate to an Android project?

Tags: android, ssl, server

I know very few things about the communication between a client and a server, and even less about SSL but I am part of a project in which I develop an android app which reads data on a server.
I used to open a socket without any security on the server but we decided to protect the server with SSL. The guy who did this sent me a .crt file which is the public key and a truststore file which has the .jks format.

I have been asked to add this certificate in the android project. But I cannot find how to do this. That's why I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to add a certificate in an Android project in order to open a SSLSocket.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Google has a [special guide](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl) for cases like yours.

Here is a little quote about what you need:

> Unknown certificate authority
>   In this case, the SSLHandshakeException occurs because you have a CA that isn't trusted by the system. It could be because you have a certificate from a new CA that isn't yet trusted by Android or your app is running on an older version without the CA. More often a CA is unknown because it isn't a public CA, but a private one issued by an organization such as a government, corporation, or education institution for their own use.
>
> Fortunately, you can teach HttpsURLConnection to trust a specific set of CAs. The procedure can be a little convoluted, so below is an example that takes a specific CA from an InputStream, uses it to create a KeyStore, which is then used to create and initialize a TrustManager. A TrustManager is what the system uses to validate certificates from the server and—by creating one from a KeyStore with one or more CAs—those will be the only CAs trusted by that TrustManager.
>
> Given the new TrustManager, the example initializes a new SSLContext which provides an SSLSocketFactory you can use to override the default SSLSocketFactory from HttpsURLConnection. This way the connection will use your CAs for certificate validation.
>
> Here is the example in full using an organizational CA from the University of Washington:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

So just put your crt file to resources folder and then run this code, changing the `caInput` to:

```
InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
```

Comment: Where should I put the file, which directory?

Comment: @IgniteCoders create raw directory inside res directory